# Create sequence for opportunity

Tags: odoo

I am using Openerp 6.1.1.

I want to create a sequence for only leads that become opportunity but not for all leads.

Since both leads and opportunity are modelled using the same table, it's not clear how to achieve this. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got this working finally.

Overriding **convert_opportunity()** was not possible since it may contain a list of ids which I couldn't figure out how to pass the sequence to. So I had to overwrite the **_convert_opportunity_data()** method (not a good choice though !).

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context={}):
    if vals['type']=='opportunity':
        next_seq = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'crm.lead')
        vals['seq'] = next_seq
    res = super(crm_sequence, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
    return res

def _convert_opportunity_data(self, cr, uid, lead, customer, section_id=False, context=None):
    vals = super(crm_sequence, self)._convert_opportunity_data(cr, uid, lead, customer, section_id, context)
    next_eq = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'crm.lead')
    vals['seq'] = next_seq
    return vals
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a sequence field in object. And when click on Button "Convert to Opportunity"

you can assign the sequence to this lead.

OR when you want to create opportunity from Opportunity menu then you overwrite the create method and in create method check type of record if type 'opportunity' then assign the sequence in record.

Thanks

Comment: i guess i have to override convert_opportunity() method but i am not clear how to pass the sequence field's next value so it can be updated properly. Any suggestion. thanks.

Comment: you can create sequence for crm.lead in ir.squence and access it using seq = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'crm.lead'), so when click button  "convert to oppertunity" use this code